# Return value in IF statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS directive with this simple code:

```
.directive('mdToggle', () => {
    return {
        link (scope, element) {
            element.on('click', () => {

                const liElements = 0;
                const liElementsHeight = 0;

                console.log(element[0].nextElementSibling !== null);
                if (element[0].nextElementSibling !== null) {
                    const liElements = element[0].nextElementSibling.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
                    const liElementHeight = element[0].nextElementSibling.getElementsByTagName('li')[0].clientHeight;
                }

                console.log(liElements * liElementsHeight);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The if statement returns a true value but the `liElements` and `liElementHeight` only live inside the if scope. How do I return that value outside of the scope so I can use it?

Comment: remove `const` from variable declaration with in `if` block `liElements = element[0].....` and use `let` instead of `const`

Comment: You should not redefine `liElements` and `liElementsHeight` inside `if`-scope and replace `const` by `let` or `var`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not re-declare and you will be fine:

```
.directive('mdToggle', () => {
    return {
        link (scope, element) {
            element.on('click', () => {

                let liElements = 0;
                let liElementsHeight = 0;

                console.log(element[0].nextElementSibling !== null);
                if (element[0].nextElementSibling !== null) {
                    liElements = element[0].nextElementSibling.getElementsByTagName('li').length;
                    liElementHeight = element[0].nextElementSibling.getElementsByTagName('li')[0].clientHeight;
                }

                console.log(liElements * liElementsHeight);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Ah. Yea makes sense.https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html "Let declarations" clears it up.